# Is getClassName() enough to identify an activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

If I'm using an accessibility service to get the activity that user currently has opened anywhere on their device, is `event.getClassName()` enough to distinguish this activity from any other activity on the device?

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
        Log.i(TAG, event.getClassName());
    }
}
```

So is it enough or is it possible that `getClassName()` might be the same for another activity? Meaning do I have to include `event.getPackageName()` as well to ensure the activity name is unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible that getClassName() might be the same for another activity?

Yes. This is especially true for apps that use third-party libraries that supply activities.

> do I have to include event.getPackageName() as well to ensure the activity name is unique?

Yes. This is why `ComponentName` needs both the application ID and the class name.